# VBA code to copy conditional formating of one cell to unspecified range of cells

Tags: vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I am looking out for help with VBA code for conditional formatting. What I am looking for is copy formatting of my cell A1 to B2 till end of the row (that is B2:B till lastrow)

I tried the following but I know this will only format B2 cell. Can anyone help?

```
Sub FormatPainter()

Range("A1").Copy

Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub FormatPainter()
    Range("A1").Copy
    Range("B2", Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response but getting an compilation error on .Columns

Comment: Sorry, too much accostumed to be inside a "With someworksheet" block. See edited code

Comment: Still not working formatting all the rows which contains value but except B which actually needs to be formatted. :(

Comment: Well, you asked to paste format "till end of the row", and that's what my code does

Comment: Thanks. For those of you who want to work with multiple individidual cells that aren't next to each other, the following may help; for the 3rd line do the following: Range("C3,G2,G3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow, I tried the following code and it worked.

```
Sub FormatPainter()
    Range("A1").Copy
    Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Thanks for your time and support :)